# Send emails with dynamic PHP

Tags: php, sql

I want send mail which I generate from my database but I don't know how send them.

```
include 'conectar.php';
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT `Email` FROM `usuarios`");    
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$from = "company@company.com.mx";
$to = while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row[0]; echo ",";
};
$subject = "El elemento fue actualizado a la version ";
$message = "El elemento fue actualizado";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
```

Comment: You cannot assign a loop to a variable like that.

Answer (score 0):

First, I will not recommend using the mail() function to send email to multiple recipients separated with commas.

I will recommend you use SMPP classes like PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Having said that, correct your code this:

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 ); error_reporting( E_ALL ); 
include 'conectar.php'; 
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT `Email` FROM `usuarios`"); 
$from = "company@company.com.mx"; 

$to = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
   $to .= $row['Email'].","; 
}
$to = rtrim($to); //remove any trailing conna

$subject = "El elemento fue actualizado a la version ";
 $message = "El elemento fue actualizado"; 
$headers = "From:" . $from; 
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
```

Pay attention to how I rearranged your original code.

Comment: We posted basically the same answer, but I posted mine ~40 seconds after you, so you can have this one. :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton some time it is happened, but with ~40 seconds difference I would appreciate the answer because no one copy paste a answer just in a minute.

Comment: @AyazShah Maybe, but the answers are almost identical, so it wouldn't add any additional information.

Comment: I fixed an obvious syntax error, the missing semi-colon for `$to = rtrim($to)` < which would have thrown a parse error.

Comment: Still don't understand how this works but I saw a question and posted a detailed answer to help the member

Comment: And No, I don't copy any answer from any body... I simply edited the question and added some corrections / improvement